# Last two digits of $3^{7^{2016}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I need help with solving this Algebra problem:
Find the last two digits of $3^{7^{2016}}$.
Preferably using Euler's theorem.

Comment: Can you edit, is it $3^{7^{2016}}?$

Comment: Yeah it's like that, I can't seem to get the latex right

Comment: You just enclose the 3^{7} like this {3^{7}}^{2016}

Comment: @kingW3 If I'm not mistaken that's another number. Exponentiation is right associative, so $3^{7^{2016}}$ would be $3^{(7^{2016})}$.

Comment: @rubik Yeah you're right,I thought it looked the same in latex

Comment: Related: [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First observe that the last two digits of powers of $3$ repeat with a cycle of $20$ elements:
$$1,3,9,27,81,43,29,87,61,83,49,47,41,23,69,7,21,63,89,67,\ldots$$

Then it's sufficient to find the last two digits of $7^{2016}$ to arrive at the answer. The last two digits of powers of $7$ repeat with a cycle of $4$:
$$1,7,49,43,\ldots$$

Therefore
$$7^{2016} \mod 100 \equiv 7^{2016 \mod 4} = 1$$
and
$$3^{7^{2016}} \mod 100 \equiv 3^{7^{2016} \mod 100} \equiv 3^1 \mod 100 = 3.$$

It follows that the last two digits of $3^{7^{2016}}$ are $03$.

Comment: @PavleJoksović Glad I could be of help! By the way, you can use WolframAlpha to confirm the answer. [The last four digits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E%287%5E2016%29+mod+10000) are $6003$.

Comment: Yeah I went there first hoping I could find the step-by-step solution, but had to ask here. Thanks again!

Comment: IOW, we need to do two steps of [Euler's totient theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Last two digits of $7^{2016}$ are $01$.
Hence $7^{2016} = 20n+01$
$3^{20n+1} = 03 \mod 100$.
Hence the last two digits are $03$.

Comment: How'd you get the 20n?

Comment: Perhaps you could say how you found the last two digits of $7^{2016}$.

Answer (score 0):

As $7\equiv-1\pmod4,7^{2016}\equiv1$

$$3^{4m}=(10-1)^{2m}=3(1-10)^{2m}\equiv1-\binom{2m}1\cdot10^1\pmod{100}\equiv1-20m$$

$$\implies3^{4m+1}\equiv3-60m\pmod{100}\ \ \ \ (1)$$

Here $m=\dfrac{7^{2016}-1}4$

Now $7^2=50-1,7^4=(50-1)^2\equiv1\pmod{20},2016\equiv0\pmod4$

$\implies7^{2016}\equiv1\pmod{20}\implies7^{2016}-1\equiv0$

$\implies\dfrac{7^{2016}-1}4\equiv0\pmod{\dfrac{20}4}\implies5|(7^{2016}-1)$

From $(1),60m$ divisible by $60\cdot5$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), $\lambda(100)=\cdots=20$

$\displaystyle\implies3^{\left(7^{2016}\right)}\equiv3^{\left(7^{2016}\pmod{20}\right)}\pmod{100}$

Again using Carmichael function, $\lambda(20)=4\implies7^4\equiv1\pmod{20}$

$\displaystyle\implies7^{2016}\equiv7^{2016\pmod4}\pmod{20}\equiv7^0\equiv1$

Can you take it from here?